# email not being delivered for one account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, email-server, ubuntu-14.04

I have setup a [mail-in-a-box](https://mailinabox.email/) recently and it works fine for the main domain - it delivers and receives email just fine.

I wanted to add another domain, so I followed the same steps [change DNS, setup MX records, created user in the mail-in-a-box interface].

I can receive emails, I tested it sending from a gmail account. But when I reply to that test, the email does not get in my gmail account [neither inbox nor spam].

I have this log from doing a `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` while sending an email to said gmail account.

```
Aug  3 04:59:16 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=4101, TLS, session=<EfteYmQcMAB/AAAB>
Aug  3 04:59:16 mail dovecot: imap(mail@domain.net): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=943
Aug  3 04:59:18 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=4105, TLS, session=<Jjt+YmQcMQB/AAAB>
Aug  3 04:59:18 mail dovecot: imap(mail@domain.net): Disconnected: Logged out in=32 out=462
Aug  3 04:59:18 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=4107, TLS, session=<i7aBYmQcMgB/AAAB>
Aug  3 04:59:18 mail dovecot: imap(mail@domain.net): Disconnected: Logged out in=44 out=611
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[4112]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[4112]: 59E8214035B: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mail@domain.net
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail postfix/cleanup[4114]: 59E8214035B: replace: header Received: from mail.domain.ro (localhost [127.0.0.1])??(using TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))??(No client certificate requested)??by mail.domain.ro (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 59E8214 from localhost[127.0.0.1]; from=<mail@domain.net> to=<email@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.domain.ro>: Received: from authenticated-user (unknown [127.0.0.1])??(using TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))??(No client certificate requested)??by mail.domain.ro (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 59E8214035B??for <email@gmail.com>; Mon,  3 Aug 2015 11:59:38 +0300 (EEST)
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail postfix/cleanup[4114]: 59E8214035B: message-id=<a2d9a70f1c1a9b1447fbbc044a4b1f4c@domain.net>
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail postfix/qmgr[14142]: 59E8214035B: from=<mail@domain.net>, size=658, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail dovecot: lmtp(4117): Connect from 127.0.0.1
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=4118, TLS, session=<EtOyY2QcNQB/AAAB>
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail spampd[1499]: processing message <a2d9a70f1c1a9b1447fbbc044a4b1f4c@domain.net> for <email@gmail.com>
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail dovecot: imap(mail@domain.net): Disconnected: Logged out in=473 out=581
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[4112]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail spampd[1499]: clean message <a2d9a70f1c1a9b1447fbbc044a4b1f4c@domain.net> (-0.99/5.00) from <mail@domain.net> for <email@gmail.com> in 0.09s, 1171 bytes.
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail dovecot: lmtp(4117, email@gmail.com): c7FtHXotv1UVEAAAvHPqVw: sieve: msgid=<a2d9a70f1c1a9b1447fbbc044a4b1f4c@domain.net>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail postfix/lmtp[4115]: 59E8214035B: to=<email@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10025, delay=0.55, delays=0.37/0.02/0.02/0.14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <email@gmail.com> c7FtHXotv1UVEAAAvHPqVw Saved)
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail dovecot: lmtp(4117): Disconnect from 127.0.0.1: Successful quit
Aug  3 04:59:38 mail postfix/qmgr[14142]: 59E8214035B: removed
Aug  3 04:59:39 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=4120, TLS, session=<Iii/Y2QcOAB/AAAB>
Aug  3 04:59:39 mail dovecot: imap(mail@domain.net): Disconnected: Logged out in=44 out=611
Aug  3 04:59:39 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=4122, TLS, session=<ijDIY2QcOQB/AAAB>
Aug  3 04:59:39 mail dovecot: imap(mail@domain.net): Disconnected: Logged out in=290 out=1375
Aug  3 04:59:40 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=4124, TLS, session=<neDKY2QcOgB/AAAB>
Aug  3 04:59:40 mail dovecot: imap(mail@domain.net): Disconnected: Logged out in=120 out=743
```

Can someone please help me figure out what is going on?
The setup is fairly recent, half an hour. I'm mentioning this in case it has something to do with DNS propagation - although I think that if that were the case I would have problems receiving email, not sending them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log entries you posted don't appear to show an outgoing delivery attempt.  The e-mail to `email@gmail.com` looks like it got delivered locally, which would tend to indicate something extremely screwed up in `virtual_domains`, since your mail server appears to think that it should receive mail for gmail.  Beyond that, who knows what mysteries mail-in-a-box may be up to behind the scenes.

Comment: this may in fact be more helpful than you might think. when I said gmail I was actually referring to google apps, and the email I tested sending to is the same email I have as an admin to mail-in-a-box. I think it confuses it somehow. just tested it with several disposable email services [guerrillamail.com, temp-mail.org, getairmail.com, throwawaymail.com] and I received all of them just fine. thanks! :)

Comment: removing any email addresses from that domain and *all aliases* from Mail-in-a-box resolved the issue.